# array sorting problem(failing for some testcases)

Tags: c, debugging

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sorting-array-of-strings/
the program i've written is failing for 3 of the testcases.
my code-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int lexicographic_sort(const char* a, const char* b) {
    if (strcmp(a,b)>0)
    return 1;
    else
    return 0;
}

int lexicographic_sort_reverse(const char* a, const char* b) {
    if (strcmp(a,b)<0)
    return 1;
    else
    return 0;
}

int sort_by_number_of_distinct_characters(const char* a, const char* b) {
    int count1[26]={0},count2[26]={0};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++)
    {
        count1[a[i]-97]++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(b); i++)
    {
        count2[b[i]-97]++;
    }
    int distict1=0,distict2=0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (count1[i]>0)
        distict1++;
        if (count2[i]>0)
        distict2++;
    }

    if (distict1>distict2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (distict1<distict2)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return lexicographic_sort(a,b);
    }
    
}

int sort_by_length(const char* a, const char* b) {
    if (strlen(a)>strlen(b))
    return 1;
    else if (strlen(a)<strlen(b))
    return 0;
    else
    return lexicographic_sort(a,b);
}

void string_sort(char** arr,const int len,int (*cmp_func)(const char* a, const char* b)){


    char store[2500];
    
    for (int j = 0; j < len - 1; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < len - j - 1; i++)
        {
            if ((*cmp_func)(arr[i],arr[i+1]))
            {
                strcpy(store,arr[i]); 
                strcpy(arr[i],arr[i+1]);
                strcpy(arr[i+1],store);
            }
        }
    }

}


int main() 
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
  
    char** arr;
    arr = (char**)malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
  
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        *(arr + i) = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
        scanf("%s", *(arr + i));
        *(arr + i) = realloc(*(arr + i), strlen(*(arr + i)) + 1);
    }
  
    string_sort(arr, n, lexicographic_sort);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");

    string_sort(arr, n, lexicographic_sort_reverse);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]); 
    printf("\n");

    string_sort(arr, n, sort_by_length);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);    
    printf("\n");

    string_sort(arr, n, sort_by_number_of_distinct_characters);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]); 
    printf("\n");
}
```

one of the failing testcase is

```
24
kkhcvkjrjcbyqixf
rbbxaogunbzkusueaycmhvvlwwdg
jdnmekotqiiuhuocqveozqyuol
mpbhaeumlebgxlotvkjxaedqfvqblcuxrxfrbbfmi
sfuiarujowqtnvodxaftz
qerrixgqfax
jxsdgicwbpssursc
rccyuvgtbyycvcnuuscfuziltagms
ymmamgvuzzsabpeqjailfdm
ohqwtlitxvtjdrddqxftmjjxlrkrwzhngxlci
xhprssixxauetipchbv
usrbhzasdlmbsduly
kvefczprbxuyposirzjuupfiszmmmkqxhwe
vtdyqzwhorrhsdbmsivmkjywvqveozqjvtjlshviyosr
tflecxolxmgnil
jdmewxsqfnbfdtwxoeisgiiufv
vdnyoqntoklhraixfdvcrzlkgvsacncxs
yhkncbxnkppsmuvjxmjkyrhrtjgvjbphkcumdtbpiqh
meglsrvrickbosyxvqefsar
tumemvczbk
tbimlmwoarnzmffuzfnybikhuhlviwidzsqngobjfqiuv
outduwlefinrdvpnbofrdmffvnvfjtt
ppckloqt
ekbbzrcpyvtmbajqxpzsiyixculqmgosqsurl
```

its expected output is-

```
ekbbzrcpyvtmbajqxpzsiyixculqmgosqsurl
jdmewxsqfnbfdtwxoeisgiiufv
jdnmekotqiiuhuocqveozqyuol
jxsdgicwbpssursc
kkhcvkjrjcbyqixf
kvefczprbxuyposirzjuupfiszmmmkqxhwe
meglsrvrickbosyxvqefsar
mpbhaeumlebgxlotvkjxaedqfvqblcuxrxfrbbfmi
ohqwtlitxvtjdrddqxftmjjxlrkrwzhngxlci
outduwlefinrdvpnbofrdmffvnvfjtt
ppckloqt
qerrixgqfax
rbbxaogunbzkusueaycmhvvlwwdg
rccyuvgtbyycvcnuuscfuziltagms
sfuiarujowqtnvodxaftz
tbimlmwoarnzmffuzfnybikhuhlviwidzsqngobjfqiuv
tflecxolxmgnil
tumemvczbk
usrbhzasdlmbsduly
vdnyoqntoklhraixfdvcrzlkgvsacncxs
vtdyqzwhorrhsdbmsivmkjywvqveozqjvtjlshviyosr
xhprssixxauetipchbv
yhkncbxnkppsmuvjxmjkyrhrtjgvjbphkcumdtbpiqh
ymmamgvuzzsabpeqjailfdm

ymmamgvuzzsabpeqjailfdm
yhkncbxnkppsmuvjxmjkyrhrtjgvjbphkcumdtbpiqh
xhprssixxauetipchbv
vtdyqzwhorrhsdbmsivmkjywvqveozqjvtjlshviyosr
vdnyoqntoklhraixfdvcrzlkgvsacncxs
usrbhzasdlmbsduly
tumemvczbk
tflecxolxmgnil
tbimlmwoarnzmffuzfnybikhuhlviwidzsqngobjfqiuv
sfuiarujowqtnvodxaftz
rccyuvgtbyycvcnuuscfuziltagms
rbbxaogunbzkusueaycmhvvlwwdg
qerrixgqfax
ppckloqt
outduwlefinrdvpnbofrdmffvnvfjtt
ohqwtlitxvtjdrddqxftmjjxlrkrwzhngxlci
mpbhaeumlebgxlotvkjxaedqfvqblcuxrxfrbbfmi
meglsrvrickbosyxvqefsar
kvefczprbxuyposirzjuupfiszmmmkqxhwe
kkhcvkjrjcbyqixf
jxsdgicwbpssursc
jdnmekotqiiuhuocqveozqyuol
jdmewxsqfnbfdtwxoeisgiiufv
ekbbzrcpyvtmbajqxpzsiyixculqmgosqsurl

ppckloqt
tumemvczbk
qerrixgqfax
tflecxolxmgnil
jxsdgicwbpssursc
kkhcvkjrjcbyqixf
usrbhzasdlmbsduly
xhprssixxauetipchbv
sfuiarujowqtnvodxaftz
meglsrvrickbosyxvqefsar
ymmamgvuzzsabpeqjailfdm
jdmewxsqfnbfdtwxoeisgiiufv
jdnmekotqiiuhuocqveozqyuol
rbbxaogunbzkusueaycmhvvlwwdg
rccyuvgtbyycvcnuuscfuziltagms
outduwlefinrdvpnbofrdmffvnvfjtt
vdnyoqntoklhraixfdvcrzlkgvsacncxs
kvefczprbxuyposirzjuupfiszmmmkqxhwe
ekbbzrcpyvtmbajqxpzsiyixculqmgosqsurl
ohqwtlitxvtjdrddqxftmjjxlrkrwzhngxlci
mpbhaeumlebgxlotvkjxaedqfvqblcuxrxfrbbfmi
yhkncbxnkppsmuvjxmjkyrhrtjgvjbphkcumdtbpiqh
vtdyqzwhorrhsdbmsivmkjywvqveozqjvtjlshviyosr
tbimlmwoarnzmffuzfnybikhuhlviwidzsqngobjfqiuv

ppckloqt
qerrixgqfax
tumemvczbk
tflecxolxmgnil
usrbhzasdlmbsduly
jxsdgicwbpssursc
kkhcvkjrjcbyqixf
xhprssixxauetipchbv
outduwlefinrdvpnbofrdmffvnvfjtt
rccyuvgtbyycvcnuuscfuziltagms
sfuiarujowqtnvodxaftz
jdmewxsqfnbfdtwxoeisgiiufv
jdnmekotqiiuhuocqveozqyuol
meglsrvrickbosyxvqefsar
ymmamgvuzzsabpeqjailfdm
vtdyqzwhorrhsdbmsivmkjywvqveozqjvtjlshviyosr
ohqwtlitxvtjdrddqxftmjjxlrkrwzhngxlci
vdnyoqntoklhraixfdvcrzlkgvsacncxs
yhkncbxnkppsmuvjxmjkyrhrtjgvjbphkcumdtbpiqh
kvefczprbxuyposirzjuupfiszmmmkqxhwe
rbbxaogunbzkusueaycmhvvlwwdg
ekbbzrcpyvtmbajqxpzsiyixculqmgosqsurl
mpbhaeumlebgxlotvkjxaedqfvqblcuxrxfrbbfmi
tbimlmwoarnzmffuzfnybikhuhlviwidzsqngobjfqiuv
```

Comment: Unless all the strings are the same length, that `strcpy()`ing of strings in the sort function is not going to play well with allocating just enough space for each one like you're doing. Why not just swap the pointers instead of their contents?

Comment: Why not just `return strcmp(a, b);` and `return lexicographic_sort(b, a);` in the reverse function? And why is the expected output much longer than the input and doesn't include all strings given as input?

Comment: Also: Do not use "magic" numbers like `97`. Use `'a'` to make it clear what you want.

Comment: @TedLyngmo the output is longer as its printing all the 4 types of sorting. also your suggestion of pointers was very helpful.

Comment: _"the output is longer as its printing all the 4 types of sorting"_ - Aha, my bad :-) _"your suggestion of pointers..."_ - Uh? I didn't suggest using pointers, did I?

Comment: I agree with @Shawn, you should consider swapping the pointers instead of the contents.